# integrate cppcheck into build system

Tags: makefile, cppcheck

I want to integrate cppcheck into my project in order to automatically produce fail on build if something is wrong. This could be part of CI job of course, but currently we have some technical issues doing that. The easiest way would be to integrate cppcheck into Makefile. Also it could use header directories configured for the project.

Is it possible and how to do that?

```make
CC=gcc
CFLAGS=-I.
DEPS = 
OBJ = main.o 

%.o: %.c $(DEPS)
        $(CC) -c -o $@ $< $(CFLAGS)

hellomake: $(OBJ)
        gcc -o $@ $^ $(CFLAGS)
```

I want to perform static analysis on `main.c`:

```c++
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    printf("hello\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show [the code you have so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include at least an outline (but preferably a [mcve]) of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Comment: Sorry, I didn't really get it. What kind of code would you like to see here?  It's generic question about cppcheck usage. I know how to run cppcheck from command line, however I don't see how can I integrate it to the build process to check all sources I have configured in makefile and use the same include directories I have there. There is no source code and no example I can show. It's a question about cppcheck usage.

Comment: It's not clear which bit you're having trouble with - perhaps a small Makefile with your proposed `check` rule would help, and an explanation of what's failing (or, what's succeeding that should fail).

Comment: added example of makefile

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is to make your default target depend both on the binary and on cppcheck's output:

```
SOURCES = main.cpp
CPPCHECK = cppcheck
CHECKFLAGS = -q --error-exitcode=1

default: cppcheck.out.xml hellomake
.PHONY: default clean

cppcheck.out.xml: $(SOURCES)
    $(CPPCHECK) $(CHECKFLAGS) $^ -xml >$@

hellomake: $(OBJ)
    $(LINK.c) -o $@ $^
```